# In a child class, how to get different types for a specific property?

Tags: c#, oop, class, inheritance

I have the following classes:

```
class BusinessBase {     }

class BusnessChild: BusinessBase {     }

class VisualBase
{
     BusinessBase BusinessObject {get; set;}
}

class VisualChild: VisualBase
{
    // I'm instantiate an instance of BusinessChild and 
    // assign it to BusinessObject property
}
```

In every instance visual child there's an object of `BusinessChild` instance from that appropriate type.

I mean they are `BusinessChild1` and `BusinessChild2` for `VisualChild1` and `VisualChild2` and all of them are inherited from `VisualBase` and `BusinessBase`.

---

**The question is:**

Is there a way to get an instance of `BusinessChild` from `VisualChild` without creating a new property in the child class? because I want to deal with all children instances from a parent reference.

What I thought so far is creating a generic method called `GetBusinessObject<T>` and pass the appropriate business type to it, **but I wonder if it can be done automatically** in someway (without passing the type).

Please ask me for further information if it's not clear.

Answer (score 3):

One obvious approach is to make `VisualBase` generic:

```
class VisualBase<T> where T : BusinessBase
{
    T BusinessObject {get; set;}
}

class VisualChild1 : VisualBase<BusinessChild1>
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sometimes being second fastest is one place worse than what it takes :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I'm embarrassed because I didn't think of a Generic class, maybe because I haven't used it before. Thank you very much

Comment: @French Boy: No need to be embarrassed - I just hope it does what you need :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: It absolutely does. Thanks. it solves the problem in a professional way.

Comment: One problem with this solution is that VisualBase is no common base class anymore, since generic specializations have no relationship in terms of oop, so property BusinessObject cannot be called without knowing the specific class.

Comment: @codymanix: That's actually a *benefit*, as it means that you can't accidentally set the wrong kind of business object on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could decorate the derived class with a custom attribute:

```
[BusinessObjectTypeAttribute(typeof(VisualChild))]
class VisualChild: VisualBase
{
    // I'm instantiate an instance of BusinessChild and 
    // assign it to BusinessObject property
}
```

Then you read out this attribute with `GetCustomAttributes()` and create the instance with `Activator.CreateInstance()` and pass the type to it.